# Can't change the text of a TextView with string passed through intent

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, textview

I'm doing a very simple login screen where the user inputs their username and password, clicks the login button, and then the inputs are displayed on the next screen.

I get a `NullPointerException` every time I try to change the textview values.  I've been googling for a long time and come up with nothing, and it has to be something simple that I'm just completely missing.

Following is my code:

```
public class LoggedIn extends Activity{
    String username = "";
    String password = "";

    TextView name;
    TextView pwd;

    Button infoDisp;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.logged_in);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.username);
        pwd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.password);

        username = intent.getStringExtra("nameInfo");
        password = intent.getStringExtra("passInfo");

        name.setText(username);
        pwd.setText(password);

    }
}
```

Edit: I changed the bundle to an intent above, also here's the rest of the code (The first activity)

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    Button loginBtn;
    Button registerBtn;
    EditText username;
    EditText pword;
    static String name;
    static String pass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        username = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.username);
        pword = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.password);
        loginBtn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0){
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoggedIn.class);
                name = username.getText().toString();
                pass = pword.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra("nameInfo", name);
                intent.putExtra("passInfo", pass);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

}

I have no error checking for if the value is null on purpose because this was supposed to be just a quick run and done thing. I figure as long as I input something in each EditText, then the strings can't be null and I won't have a problem... right?

Stacktrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.loginscreen, PID: 1677
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.loginscreen/com.example.loginscreen.LoggedIn}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.loginscreen.LoggedIn.onCreate(LoggedIn.java:30)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
    ... 11 more
```

Aaaand xml files:
  activity_login:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".LoginActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Login:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:text="Password:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="Login" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/registerBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/loginBtn"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/loginBtn"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
    android:text="Register" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/remPass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/loginBtn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/loginBtn"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="Remember Password" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/remPass"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Forgot Password" />
```

logged_in:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".LoginActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Logged In!"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:text="Username: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:text="Password: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recUsername"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:editable="true"
    android:text=" "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
    android:editable="true"
    android:text=" "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/infoBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:text="Press to Display Info" />
```

Comment: Show your all code plz.

Comment: Check the values of name and pwd...i think you are getting null values for name and pwd

Comment: Add some code... how you are sending the values to this activity....

Comment: post stacktrace which line you are getting NullPointerException...

Comment: Post the layout codes. The NUllPointerException could be bcoz yu referenced wrong ids when initialization of views. post `activity_login.xml`

Comment: YOUR PROBLEM SOLVED OR NOT?

Comment: I just posted everything so it took me a bit. No it's not solved yet.

Comment: @user3349697 as i had guessed referencing wrong ids. check the id of your textviews in respective layouts

Comment: sorry I put the xmls backwards from what i posted, so the first xml is for the first activity (which is the second code post)

Comment: @user3349697 check my post that should solve your problem

Comment: I can't believe I missed that... wow. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are finding id for TextView s are wrong.. so just change from

```
    username = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.username);
    pword = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.password);
```

to

```
    username = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.recUsername);
    pword = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.recPassword);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace this in your **LoggedIn Activity**. You have wrong ids when initialization of views `logged_in.xml`

```
    username = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.username);
    pword = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.password);
    loginBtn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
```

With

```
    TextView username = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.recUsername);
    TextView pword = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.recPassword);
    loginBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.infoBtn);
```

Comment: Must check that in **logged_in** he never used EditText. Its textview. So change your Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.username);
 pwd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.password);
```

to

```
 name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.recUsername);
 pwd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.recPassword);
```

In `LoggedIn.java`

Your `NUllPointerExceptipon` is ccoz you referencing wrong ids for your views. `findViewById` looks for a view in the current infalted layout. Since it does not find one. Your initialization fails leading to `NullPointerExcpetion`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this...

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
```

to...

```
Intent bundle = getIntent();
```

Then use this to retrieve extras....

```
username = bundle.getStringExtra("nameInfo");
password = bundle.getStringExtra("passInfo");
```

**Update:**

You are trying to get `TextView`s using those `id`s which does not exist in the current layout xml...that is, you are using wrong `id` to retrieve your `Textview`s. So, change those `id`s in these following lines...

```
username = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.username);
pword = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.password);
```

to

```
username = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.recUsername);
pword = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.recPassword);
```

Comment: I started with this and changed back to it but it doesn't seem to help. I posted the rest of my code above if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with following line

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoggedIn.class);
```

change it to

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoggedIn.class);
```

or

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoggedIn.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your LoggedIn class the ids are wrong

```
name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.username);
pwd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.password);
```

change the above ids to defined ids in the logged_in.xml layout and try again